# window["Lugar"]["NombreFuncion"]("argumento") No funciona

Tags: javascript

Dispongo de una web con múltiples iframes, para navegar entre ellos tengo una clase javascript que genera una pestaña y asigna un evento de cierre a esa misma, el problema es que, al pulsar el botón de cierre ejecuta sin mostrar error, pero no realiza la función. El evento de cierre es:

```
function anadirEvento() {
        var closebtns = window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName("cerrar");
        var i;
        console.log("closebtns",closebtns);
        for (i = 0; i < closebtns.length; i++) {
            closebtns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                var padre = this.parentElement;
                var padrepadre = padre.parentElement;
                //Elimina la pestaña
                padre.remove();
                //obtengo la función de la siguiente pestaña abierta
                var regexp = /\b(verOpcion\([0-9]{1,2})\b/i;
                var pestana = closebtns[closebtns.length - 1].parentElement.outerHTML;
                var funcion = pestana.match(regexp)[0].split("(");
                
                var nombre = funcion[0];
                var valor = funcion[1];
                //compruebo que los valores son: verOpcion y el numero que necesito como argumento
                console.log("pestana", nombre, valor);
                window["pestanas"][nombre](valor);
            });
        }
    }
```

He probado también con [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval) pero obtengo el mismo resultado, no hay errores de ejecución pero no ejecuta la función, cambiando la regexp a `/\b(verOpcion\([0-9]{1,2}\))` para obtener la función completa.

Se que funciona el evento porque si miro en la consola veo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que si la ejecuta pero no realiza las ordenes, que es básicamente mostrar el iframe, en el caso de la imagen, el 7.

**¿Por que no realiza la función?**